# Find an Eulerian path or circuit in a graph given its adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Consider the graph with adjacency matrix
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

Can you find an Eulerian path or circuit in this graph? What is it?

Comment: The graph is cubic (i.e., $3$-regular), so...

Comment: Good point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make my comment an answer/hint [if just to reduce the unanswered queue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12367/comment-answer-dilemma-from-the-commentator-point-of-view?cb=1) by $\epsilon$.

**Hint:** From the adjacency matrix, you can see that the graph is $3$-regular. In particular, there are at least $3$ vertices of odd degree.

Comment: Nicest hint I've seen today. +1

Answer (score 0):

In order for a graph to contain an Eulerian path or circuit there must be zero or two nodes of odd valence. This graphs has more than two, therefore it cannot contain any Eulerian paths or circuits.